# Either counting or filtering an array of random integers based on specific characteristics

Tags: java, arrays, filter

My problem is that I must create an array of random integers from 0-100 and count the number of single digit integers that are produced.

So far I have this:

```
public class randomarray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i;
        int smallintegers;
        int[] RandomArray = new int[10];
        for(i = 0; i <  RandomArray.length; i++) {
            RandomArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.print(RandomArray[i] + "  ");
            }
    }
}
```

This works and creates an array of random digits like so:

```
17  56  44  41  42  96  8  42  21  86
```

Now I need to find out a way to count the number of single digit integers, and in this case it would have been 1.

The first method I thought of would be to use `filter()` to copy the single-digit integers, create a new array from `filter()`, and then produce the length of the new array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about checking for single digit integers while you are building the array:

```
int numSingle = 0;
for (i=0; i < RandomArray.length; i++) {
    int num = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
    if (num < 10) ++numSingle;
    RandomArray[i] = num;
    System.out.print(num + "  ");
}

System.out.println("There are " + numSingle + " integers in the array.");
```

If, for some reason, you can't check the array as it's being built (e.g. you are receiving it from some API you can't control), then you can go with the Wombat's suggestion to just iterate the array.  If you use a Java 8 stream to do this I expect it would also iterate over the array internally.

Here is how you could use a stream to answer the same question:

```
int numSingle = Arrays.stream(RandomArray).filter(n -> n < 10).toArray().length;
```

Comment: Can't get any simpler

Comment: I knew I was just being dumb about it. Sorry and thanks.
P.S. is it possible to do it in the way that I mentioned, with filter()?

Comment: @KasparFroyen I gave you an option using streams and filter.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple yet not as elegant way to accomplish this would be to convert each integer to a string and use string.length. I know I am not allowed to use lambda expressions in my classes so this is a route that doesn't include it.